# Retrieve Field Rows from a Pipe Delimited File

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, awk

I need to get first 9 words from a pipe delimited file and then next 9 words.

```
 cat a.txt
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|
```

cat new.ksh

```
#! /bin/ksh
a=`awk -F "|" ' { print NF-1 } ' a.txt`
echo $a
```

Expected Output:

```
grep -i "a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i" b.txt >> c.txt
grep -i "j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r" b.txt >> c.txt
grep -i "s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z" b.txt >> c.txt
```

Comment: Also, you'll need quotes to prevent newlines from being translated to spaces: `echo "$a"`

Comment: @Thanks for your response. It should be there as well.

Comment: What's in `b.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed

```
sed -E 's/(([^|]+\|){1,9})/\1\n/g' a.txt
```

or perl

```
perl -F'\|' -lanE 'while (@F) {say join("|", splice @F, 0, 9), "|"}' a.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn for your help. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$ tr '|' $'\n' < file | paste -sd'||||||||\n'
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i
j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r
s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|
```

Comment: Thanks RudiC but  glenn solution is very simple with one pipe delimiter.

Comment: @Josh "Simple" is one of those words with a very variable meaning.

Comment: @Kusalananda I didnt mean it in a negative way :) Simple is something easy to use.